# bluetoothctl: can't input commands

Tags: bluetooth, services, dbus, bluez

After installing the latest Bluez package, I ran bluetoothctl. The program starts in the command line and prompts for user input. However, it does not respond to any user input whatsoever.

Searching the Internet I found there were a couple of possible causes:

**Bluetooth Daemon is not running**

```
zim@acer:~/bluez/client$ ps aux | grep bluetoothd

root      6497  0.0  0.0  19432  3664 ?        Ss   12:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
zim       6681  0.0  0.0  15952  2256 pts/7    S+   12:37   0:00 grep --color=auto bluetoothd
```

Confirmed that it is running.

**D-Bus Daemon is not running**

```
message+   755  0.0  0.0  40404  4080 ?        Ss   11:06   0:01 dbus-daemon --system --fork
zim     1268  0.0  0.0  40488  4164 ?        Ss   11:06   0:02 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-FCRAG72Dib
zim     1312  0.0  0.0  22412  1904 ?        S    11:06   0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session
zim     1316  0.0  0.0  22316   224 ?        S    11:06   0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system
zim     1348  0.0  0.0  39376  3520 ?        S    11:06   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
nobody    1405  0.0  0.0  35232  3216 ?        S    11:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
zim     6837  0.0  0.0  39116   332 ?        Ss   13:01   0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
zim     7285  0.0  0.0  15952  2324 pts/7    S+   13:02   0:00 grep --color=auto dbus
```

Confirmed that it is running.

`hcitool` and such work fine and I can scan for devices.

I wouldn't know how to troubleshoot this problem. The source code isn't clear about this looking at it unskilled.

Can anyone confirm it isn't working properly?
Are there any steps I could take in order to find the root of this problem? The tool is unusable.

Comment: I have the same problem on Arch, however I don't see anything from `hcitool` as well.

Comment: `hcitool` should work then, you got all the packages and such? Maybe you could make a separate question detailing it? I could try and answer!

Comment: `bluedevil-wizard` made it for me.

Comment: What did it make?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to investigate or understand it. I just installed and ran `bluedevil-wizard` and clicked whatever the GUI suggested. Afterwards `bluetoothctl` became responsive.  Now it's still responsive, but `connect` command raises an error until I click "Fix pairing" on `bluedevil-wizard`, after that it connects to my audio sink and that's all I needed for that day. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu Wiley unstable, I found this working as expected. The problem was that I was using Ubuntu 14 with Bluez 4.x

Any BlueZ version 5.x will allow the use of bluetoothctl. 4.x has been deprecated for a while. For more information about BlueZ and its use, check my questions and answers on stackoverflow.